# Six doors, two are survivable, your pick

Tags: riddle, odd-one-out

It's the middle of the day. You're locked up in a room with only six doors to freedom.

- The first door holds a raging fire
- The second door is filled with armed assassins waiting to kill you
- The third door has several broken high voltage wires hanging on the ceiling with water covering the floor one inch deep
- The fourth door holds an alligator who hasn't eaten for a year
- The fifth door holds several solar lights powerful enough to incinerate you
- The sixth door contains a flesh-hungry werewolf

Which two doors are safe?

Comment: You certainly didn't let this run for very long.  I was looking during the night and it wasn't here, and now this morning, you've given the answer before I ever saw the riddle!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any door with the right conditions!

1

> Wait for the fire to stop.

2

> The assassins are dying.

3

> The ceiling is at 30m height, and all wires are maximum 1m long.

4

> It is probably dead(they could go 3 years without eating), but let's say it was just born a year ago, so never ate in it's life, so it is dead.

5

> The lights are off.

6

> The werewolf is dying.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously

> The fourth door, as the aligator would be dead by now.

And

> The third door, just don't touch the wires.

Or

> The fifth door, if the solar lights are off.

Comment: To you and everyone else who guessed the alligator room, you're actually wrong! Alligators can survive 2-3 years without food.

Answer (score 1):

I guess

> door number four, as the alligator is probably dead by now (although Nopalaa says they can live 3 years without eating...)

and

> number six, as werewolf will turn back to a human shape as soon as you open the door and let the mid-day light in there, so there is no real danger there.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

> Doors numbered 3 and 4 (as which two doors are asked)

As,

> broken high voltage lines and an alligator not eaten for a year are definitely safe bets.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some answers, but here is my logic.

> Door 4 is safe. The alligator is dead.
>  Being mid day, go for door number 6. The werewolf will not be werewolf because no moon and stuff..
>  or... wait for the night to come and go through door #5 because the solar panels have no power at night.

Comment: You got six right but I haven't actually thought about that for number five, maybe I should have added something like 'there's also a bomb and you have to escape in only a few minutes" or something like that

Comment: Maybe you should have, but you didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

> Werewolves and solar lights would be my pick, being the middle of the day.

Answer (score 0):

For the answer:

> To everyone who guessed the alligator room, you are absolutely...
>   WRONG!
>  Alligators can survive without food for a year (they can survive 2-3 actually)
>  The two that were safe were the third door and the sixth
>  For the third, the wires aren't touching the water, so as long as you don't touch both at once, you're fine.
>  As for the sixth, it's day time. Werewolves are only werewolves by night on a full moon.

Answer (score 0):

I think 3 and 6. As in 3, the wires are at ceiling and water at the floor so you can easily go through it. And 6, the werewolf will turn into human when its day so you can go through it also.

Thanks